# MySql inner join results duplicates values

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, join

I have two tables (product, cart) and I want to make a query do get a product which matches to my need.

```
SELECT * FROM product;
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| id | description | image | name          | quantity | supplier_id | productid | product_id |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------+
| 8  | Desc 1      | NULL  | Product 1     | NULL     | 6           | NULL      | NULL       |
| 15 | asd         | NULL  | asd           | NULL     | 6           | NULL      | NULL       |
| 35 | asdsadsad   | NULL  | test producdt | NULL     | 6           | NULL      | NULL       |
| 45 | NULL        | NULL  | asdas         | NULL     | 6           | 514       | NULL       |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

```
SELECT * FROM cart;
```

```
+-----+-------+----------+------------+---------+
| id  | price | quantity | product_id | user_id |
+-----+-------+----------+------------+---------+
| 141 | 100   | 1        | 8          | 26      |
| 139 | 100   | 1        | 8          | 26      |
+-----+-------+----------+------------+---------+
```

```
SELECT *
FROM product
INNER JOIN cart
    ON cart.user_id = 26
    AND cart.product_id = product.id
    AND product.supplier_id = 6
```

```
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----+-------+----------+------------+---------+
| id | description | image | name          | quantity | supplier_id | productid | product_id | id  | price | quantity | product_id | user_id |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----+-------+----------+------------+---------+
| 8  | Desc 1      | NULL  | Product 1     | NULL     | 6           | NULL      | NULL       | 141 | 100   | 1        | 8          | 26      |
| 8  | Desc 1      | NULL  | Product 1     | NULL     | 6           | NULL      | NULL       | 139 | 100   | 1        | 8          | 26      |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------+----------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----+-------+----------+------------+---------+
```

**Cart**

```
@Entity
public class Cart extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
    private Integer quantity;
    private Double price;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "cart_property_option",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "property_option_id"))
    private Set<PropertyOption> selectedPropertyOptions;


    public Cart() {
    }

    public Cart(User user, Product product, Integer quantity) {
        this.user = user;
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<PropertyOption> getSelectedPropertyOptions() {
        return selectedPropertyOptions;
    }

    public void setSelectedPropertyOptions(Set<PropertyOption> selectedPropertyOptions) {
        this.selectedPropertyOptions = selectedPropertyOptions;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof Cart)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.id.equals(((Cart) obj).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * 17 + id.hashCode();
    }
}
```

**Product**

```
@Entity
public class Product extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String productId;
    private String image;
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    private Supplier supplier;
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Cart> carts;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Price> prices;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_productCategory",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private Set<ProductCategory> productCategories;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Property> properties;

    public void addProperty(Property property){
        if(properties == null) {
            properties = new HashSet<>();
        }
        properties.add(property);
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Supplier getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public void setSupplier(Supplier supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public Set<Cart> getCarts() {
        return carts;
    }

    public void setCarts(Set<Cart> carts) {
        this.carts = carts;
    }


    public Set<Price> getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

    public void setPrices(Set<Price> prices) {
        this.prices = prices;
    }

    public Set<ProductCategory> getProductCategories() {
        return productCategories;
    }

    public void setProductCategories(Set<ProductCategory> productCategories) {
        this.productCategories = productCategories;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Set<Property> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Set<Property> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting 2 products with the same hashcode and each have 2 carts in it,instead I want to get one product.I added the same product with different properties which constructed `Cart` table.

Can someone help me to do the right query ?

Comment: Please don't post images for sample data instead include sample data in textual format or better to use any online tool, Also include your complete table definitions and expected output

Comment: What language is this? It doesn't look like SQL. It looks like some kind of ORM framework. You should tag the question with the language and framework.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I can see that the Product entity does not implement the `hashCode()` method and I assume that this should be implemented in the super class which is `BaseEntity`. If you could check that I'm correct maybe the implementation of `hashCode()` in that class is wrong or is a constant.

Could please also put the code that you are using to get the products related to a cart? Maybe It's something wrong there.

Comment: I solved it by changing my Product List into Set, but thank you :)

Comment: Ok, that 'll work but you should take a look to your implementation and the query you are using just to be sure. From a performance perspective that unique filter is being done in the java side instead of the database side which should be better and more effective.